# FTP with MySQL Authentication

Tags: mysql, ftp

I know this is possible but can't remember the name of the FTP server software (free and cool) to setup FTP access for users with authentication using MySQL. For example, I can create the username and password in a MySQL table and FTP would authenticate if the user is setup on the MySQL table. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I am using CentOS and have full control of the dedicated server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: ProFTPd with MySQL module.